# altering %title

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

I'd like to transform the result from %title in functions like next_post_link().

More specificaly, I created a function called short_title($title, $after, $length).
The idea is to return the title with an $after when the title exceeds $length words.
The function works like it's supposed to do.

However, I have a hard time invoking that function.

I'm trying

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span>< ' . short_title( '%title', '...', 2) . '</span>' ); ?>
```

but that doesn't work and doesn't either when not using the ticks around %title.

Can you please explain me how to correctly invoke my function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your logic doesn't quite work out.  The reason is because the order of operations, just like math, works inside to outside.

So, your `short_title()` function is running with just passing the string `%title`, which then returns, I assume, the same string because that string meets your requirements.  Then it passes `%title` onto `previous_post_link` and returns the full title as it did before.

As for a solution, outside of writing your own custom function, there is [a filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2051) `previous_post_link` that you could try to use, but if you're only worried about the display side, you may be able to fix it with [CSS using text-overflow](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/).

Comment: Thanks socki. That's exactly what I did.
Created a child function, created a new function in functions.php and then added to previous_post_link.

Thanks